# Devise gem: add module after initial install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rubygems, devise

This may not be ***Devise*** specific but I'm wondering how to add an additional module to a gem that has already been installed *when* the initial install didn't include said module? In the case of Devise the migration helper `t.confirmable` is useful in the initial migration's `Self.up` method and the whole User table is torn down in the `Self.down`. My Rails-fu isn't strong enough to uncover what the `t.confirmable` helper is actually doing...

What happens when the `User` table already exists and you want to add something like `:confirmable` or `:token_authenticatable`?  Obviously you can't just `create_table(:users)` again... so me thinks I want to `add_column :users, ...` and `remove_column :users, ...` but how do we go about finding out what needs to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at  Devise::Schema

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/schema.rb

which has this

```
# Creates confirmation_token, confirmed_at and confirmation_sent_at.
    def confirmable
      apply_devise_schema :confirmation_token,   String
      apply_devise_schema :confirmed_at,         DateTime
      apply_devise_schema :confirmation_sent_at, DateTime
    end
```

and then

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb

```
def apply_devise_schema(name, type, options={})
    column name, type.to_s.downcase.to_sym, options
end
```

So in your migration  just do

```
 add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
 add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
 add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
```

and the opposite for the down..

Answer (score 0):

Your migration:

```
  class DeviseAddConfirmable < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       change_table(:users) do |t|
          t.confirmable
       end

       add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
     end
  end
```